# How to replace scikit-learn (make_circle) to my own dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to integrate my own dataset in scikit learn. My dataset was categorical data and I encoded to numerical data, it has 3 columns and 100 rows. The current scikit learn dataset is created using make_circle().

```
X, Y = make_circles(n_samples=n, noise=0.07, factor=0.4)
```

What I did?

I read my dataset using pandas.

```py
col_names = ['Relation', 'Entity1', 'Entity2']
# load dataset
pima = pd.read_csv("encode.csv", header=None, names=col_names)
pima.head()
```

Current Output:

```
Relation    Entity1     Entity2
 3       0       0
 0       1       2
 2       9       0
 3       5       3
 1       4       1
 2       6       0
 3       3       4
```

But I want to add this dataset based on make_circle() into 2 dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply a dimensionality reduction and bring it down to 2 dimentions.

You can use something like [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) or [UMAP](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap).

Check [this post](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/08/dimensionality-reduction-techniques-python/). It should be very useful.

Using UMAP:

```
import umap

reduced = umap.UMAP().fit_transform(pima)
```

Using PCA:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
reduced = pca.fit_tranform(pima)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, how to assign it to `X, and Y` variable as they did in `make_circle()`

Comment: well, `Y` would be your labels. Either you know them and you take them from somewhere you have them or you need to apply some clustering like HDBSCAN and then get the labels.

Comment: How it is generated here, `X, Y = make_circles(n_samples=n, noise=0.07, factor=0.4)` because I did not use labels, I just have three columns that show the relation between entities.

Comment: you can check here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/datasets/samples_generator.py#L634 how is `Y` generated. Here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_circles.html is the documentation of `make_circles`. I am not entirely sure what are you trying to achieve. I don't know what the original state of the data was. Not sure what are you trying to predict as well. To be clear - by labels I mean your predicting variable.